# Android Room does not insert object with autogenerated primary key

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I just wanted to make a very simple database app in Android Studio for the insert function and I'm trying to insert a row for the table "Items". When I run it, there are no errors. But when I'm on the app itself, after inputting the Item Name and when I save it, my app crashes. I have no problem when I manually just input the Item Id upon removing "autoGenerate=true".

I'm still very new to Room and I'm practicing. I checked out some of the questions posted here about autogenerated primary keys but I haven't found a fix yet.   I apologize in advance if this has already been asked.

Here's my definition for the Item class:

```
 @Entity(tableName = "items")
 public class Item {

  @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
  private int id;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "item_name")
  private String name;


  public int getId() {
     return id;
  }


  public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
  }


  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

My Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {


@Insert
public void addItem(Item item);

}
```

And this is my code I used for getting the info by user input and for inserting:

```
private EditText ItemName;

ItemName = view.findViewById(R.id.et_item_name); //et_item_name is an edittext
String itemname = ItemName.getText().toString();

 Item item = new Item();
 item.setName(itemname);

 MyActivity.appDatabase.mydao().addItem(item);
```

Database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Item.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract MyDao mydao();
}
```

My Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public static AppDatabase appDatabase;
    private String DB_NAME = "db_items";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries().build();    //allow main thread queries is only temporary. It's just for testing purposes.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also add the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey